# Как уменьшить значение регистра на единицу не используя инструкцию DEC?

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, x86

Как уменьшить значение регистра на единицу не используя инструкцию `dec` ? Если можно, то несколько способов.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

просто вычитание

```
sub eax, 1
```

прибавление отрицательного числа

```
add eax, -1
```

Answer (score 13):

Логическая короткая альтернатива. Возможно будет уложена в два байта.

```
          ; eax = 1    0   -1
neg eax   ; смена знака
          ; eax = -1   0    1
not eax   ; инверсия
          ; eax = 0  -1   -2
```

Ещё известный способ — `lea` — вычисление эффективного адреса:

```
lea eax, [eax - 1] ;
```

Можно не все регистры использовать, `ebx`, `ebp`, `esi`, `edi` — точно можно, другие — надо или пробовать, или читать документацию.

`lea` — особая команда лучше почитать на неё доку. Ещё `lea` не затрагивает флаги, что даёт возможность запутать код через работу с флагами.

Comment: lea и с eax будет работать (и вообще с любыми регистрами общего назначения 32 и более битными). Не будет работать с 16-битными не-базовыми и не-индексными регистрами (базовые - bp, bx, индексные - di, si). Это в целом особенности сложной адресации в x86, а не только команды lea.

Comment: Ну собственно вот какая-никакая документация: [5.3. Режимы адресации](https://studfile.net/preview/2279614/page:5/), см. таблица 5.1 (Режимы адресации процессоров IA-32). В нашем случае базовая адресация со смещением, `[Reg + Disp]`, и ниже `Reg,Reg1,Reg2 - один из регистров общего назначения (ЕАХ, ЕВХ, ЕСХ,EDX,ESP, ЕВР,ESI,EDI), с тем исключением, что регистр ESP не может использоваться в качестве индексного.`

Comment: С `lea` интересный трюк)